# HBase HFile Corruption on AWS S3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce, hbase, elastic-map-reduce

I am running ***HBase*** on an ***EMR cluster*** (emr-5.7.0) enabled on ***S3***.
 We are using '***ImportTsv***' and '***CompleteBulkLoad***' utilities for importing the data into HBase. 
 During our process, we have observed that intermittently there were failures stating that there were ***HFile corruption*** for some of the imported files. This happens sporadically and there is no pattern that we could deduce for the errors.

---

After lot of research and going through many suggestions in blogs, I have tried the below fixes but of no avail and we are still facing the discrepancy.

> ***Tech Stack :***
>
> - AWS EMR Cluster (emr-5.7.0 | r3.8xlarge | 15 nodes)
> - AWS S3
> - HBase 1.3.1

---

> ***Data Volume:***
>
> - ~ 960000 lines (To be upserted) | ~ 7GB TSV file

---

> ***Commands used in sequence:***
>
> ```
>  1) hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator="|"  -Dimporttsv.columns="<Column Names (472 Columns)>" -Dimporttsv.bulk.output="<HFiles Path on HDFS>" <Table Name> <TSV file path on HDFS> 
>  2) hadoop fs -chmod 777 <HFiles Path on HDFS>
>  3) hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles <HFiles Path on HDFS> <Table Name>
> ```

---

> ***Fixes Tried:***
>
> 1. ***Increasing S3 Max Connections:***
>
>    - We increased the below property but it did not seem to resolve the issue.  ***fs.s3.maxConnections*** : Values tried -- 10000, 20000, 50000, 100000.
> 2. ***HBase Repair:***
>
>    - Another approach was to execute the HBase repair command but it didn't seem to help either.
>        Command : ***hbase hbase hbck -repair***

---

Error Trace is as below:

> [LoadIncrementalHFiles-17] mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Received a
>   CorruptHFileException from region server: row '00218333246' on table
>   'WB_MASTER' at
>   region=WB_MASTER,00218333246,1506304894610.f108f470c00356217d63396aa11cf0bc.,
>   hostname=ip-10-244-8-74.ec2.internal,16020,1507907710216, seqNum=198
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.CorruptHFileException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.CorruptHFileException: Problem
>   reading HFile Trailer from file
>   s3://wbpoc-landingzone/emrfs_test/wb_hbase_compressed/data/default/WB_MASTER/f108f470c00356217d63396aa11cf0bc/cf/2a9ecdc5c3aa4ad8aca535f56c35a32d_SeqId_200_
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile.pickReaderVersion(HFile.java:497)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile.createReader(HFile.java:525)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile$Reader.(StoreFile.java:1170)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileInfo.open(StoreFileInfo.java:259)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile.open(StoreFile.java:427)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile.createReader(StoreFile.java:528)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile.createReader(StoreFile.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HStore.createStoreFileAndReader(HStore.java:667)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HStore.createStoreFileAndReader(HStore.java:659)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HStore.bulkLoadHFile(HStore.java:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.bulkLoadHFiles(HRegion.java:5574)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.bulkLoadHFile(RSRpcServices.java:2034)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:34952)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2339)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:168)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File not present on S3  at
>   com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem$NativeS3FsInputStream.read(S3NativeFileSystem.java:203)
>     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)    at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.FixedFileTrailer.readFromStream(FixedFileTrailer.java:391)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile.pickReaderVersion(HFile.java:482)

---

Any suggestions in figuring out the root cause for this discrepancy would be really helpful.

Appreciate your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research and trial & errors, I was finally able to find a resolution for this issue, thanks to AWS support folks. It seems the issue is an occurrence as a result of S3's eventual consistency. The AWS team suggested to use the below property and it worked like a charm, so far we haven't hit the HFile corruption issue. Hope this helps if someone is facing the same issue!

*Property* (*hbase-site.xml*): 
  ***hbase.bulkload.retries.retryOnIOException : true***